# autocomplete control with display text different than form value

Tags: android

Is there a default control or third party library available in android for creating an auto complete UI control which will allow me to use different values for display text on the control and the actual form value. For example in HTML we have  options which will allow us to set different values for value and label for it as shown below.

```
<select><option value="NJ">New Jersey</option></select>
```

I have States information in SQLlight database. I want to create an autocomplete UI control which will display the statename in autocomplete options but when selected the form value should be the statecode but not the name.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not, you can get started with this tutorial http://androidexample.com/Show_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=105&aaid=127

Comment: Thanks I know about this. This does not solve my problem. I need to be able to have a different value for display text and the actual form value.

Comment: what is "form value"? spinner/autocompletetextview does not have such a term, it has an adapter instead